# ASP.Net Core Cookies Authentication Redirects to Login

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to setup authentication using cookies but `SignInAsync` seems to not be working.

My sign method is, at the moment at least, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
{
    if (username != "foo" || password != "bar")
    {
        return View();
    }

    //Sign in
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim("name", "admin")
    };

    var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

    //Redirect
    return RedirectToAction("home");
}
```

`Home` is an action with `Authorize` attribute.
If I provide the correct username and password, I can step over the `SignInAsync` call with no exception seemingly called. However, upon redirection, I end up back at the login page as I am still not logged in.

`Startup.cs` is listed below:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/admin/login/";
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
}
```

What am I missing or how can I debug/get further information on what is going wrong?

Comment: app.UseAuthentication(); goes before UseMvc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment by Tratcher, use `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseMvc();`.